# Empty multiple select from client

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have the following model:

```
public class PushTemplatePackage
{
    public int PushTemplatePackageId { get; set; }

    public string PackageId { get; set; }
}
```

and a model that includes previous model

```
public class PushTemplate
{
    public int PushTemplateId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<PushTemplatePackage> PushTemplatePackageIds { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public PushTemplate()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

and the following controller method

```
public IActionResult Create(PushTemplate pushTemplate)
{
    // IQueryable<PushTemplatePackage>
    var appIds = _customerRepository.Customers.Select(x => x.AppId).Distinct().Select(x => new PushTemplatePackage
    {
        PackageId = x 
    });

    ViewBag.AppIds = new MultiSelectList(appIds, "PackageId", "PackageId");

    return View();
}
```

And view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "PushTemplate",
    FormMethod.Post, new {id = "pushForm"}))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Applications</label>
        @Html.ListBox("PackageId", 
        (MultiSelectList) ViewBag.AppIds, 
        new {@class = "selectpicker", title = "Choise package ID"})
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mt-1"><i class="fa fa-list" id="saveTemplate"></i> Create</button>
}
```

So business logic. I have `IQueryable<PushTemplatePackage>` on the controller. I need to show it on the view and save it after user choice. With showing, I don't have problems. But when I submit form I see that `PushTemplatePackageIds` is null. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For your current `PushTemplate`, you need to pass the request like below from client side:

```
POST /Home/Create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0b6384df-f024-4edb-93fd-0ed789d1ef40


Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PushTemplatePackageIds[0].PackageId"

P1
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PushTemplatePackageIds[0].PackageId"

P1
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PushTemplatePackageIds[1].PackageId"

P11
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

For a workaround, you may consider append `public List<string> PushTemplatePackageSelectedIds { get; set; }`
 to `PushTemplate` like

1. Model

   ```
   public class PushTemplate
   {
       public int PushTemplateId { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public List<string> PushTemplatePackageSelectedIds { get; set; }        
       public List<PushTemplatePackage> PushTemplatePackageIds { get; set; }
       public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
       public PushTemplate()
       {
           CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
       }
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home",
   FormMethod.Post, new { id = "pushForm" }))
   {
       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Applications</label>
           @Html.ListBox("PushTemplatePackageSelectedIds",
           (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.AppIds,
           new { @class = "selectpicker", title = "Choise package ID" })
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mt-1"><i class="fa fa-list" id="saveTemplate"></i> Create</button>
   }
   ```